# PHP preg_replace replacing letters after symbols

Tags: php, preg-replace

My current problem is that I have a table full of words and their abbreviations that I feed into two arrays to use later using `preg_replace`.

```
$search[] = '/\b'.$row['word'].'\b/i';  --WORDS TO ABBREVIATE
$abbrev[] = $row['abbrev'];             --LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS

//search and replace 
for($i = 0; $i<count($search); $i++)
{
     $title = = preg_replace($search[$i],$abbrev[$i], $title);
}
```

Everything seems to work ok but I have an issues where this is converted incorrect.

Heaven's Basement       -->      Heaven'S. Basement

S. being an abbreviation for South

How would I go about making sure that words or character after symbols/punctuation don't get replaced?  Any help would be totally appreciated as my understanding of regular expressions is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `\b` you could use [**assertions**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) and check for whitespace `\s` and start (`^`):

```
'/(?<=\s|^)' . $row['word'] . '\b/i'
```

Now, the word must be preceded by whitespace (or beginning of the string), instead of by any "non-word" character.

On a separate note, you don't need the loop, [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace) also works with **arrays**:

```
$title = preg_replace($search, $abbrev, $title);
```

**UPDATE:**  I had a mistake in the assertion syntax. Now it works: [running example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/baf0c454f411908c5d0e89c3ff91fb286f8299c1)

**Test code:**

```
$rows = [
  ['word' => 'S', 'abbrev' => 'South'],
  ['word' => 'W', 'abbrev' => 'West'],
  ['word' => 'N', 'abbrev' => 'North'],
  ['word' => 'E', 'abbrev' => 'East'],
];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $search[] = '/(?<=\s|^)' . preg_quote($row['word'], '/') . '\b/i';
  $abbrev[] = $row['abbrev'];
}

$title = "Heaven's Basement in W Virginia";
echo preg_replace($search, $abbrev, $title);
```

**Test result:**

```
Heaven's Basement in West Virginia
```

**UPDATE 2:** You can do the same after the word with a **lookahead** assertion and `$` (string end) instead of `^` (string beginning)

```
'/(?<=\s|^)' . preg_quote($row['word'], '/') . '(?=\s|$)/i';
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'a' and further down PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'b'.  I'm not sure why that is occurring now.

Comment: Sorry, a "/" slipped in at the wrong place, I fixed the code now. By the way, any characters in `$row['word']` that have special meaning in PCRE will be a problem too, unless you apply `preg_quote` to it first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this totally works.  I need to do some further testing but I'm pretty sure that this or Dmitrii Chekaliuk's answer solves my problem.

Comment: Is there a way to tweak this so I would have words converted if they are proceed by a symbol such as '-' as my comment to Dmitrii Chekaliuk?  This a nice to have and I appreciate your help so far.

Comment: of course it is, I even had the expression for it at first, but then thought you wrote "after" on purpose because otherwise abbreviations at the end of a sentence or before a comma would not be replaced. Looks like there are too many special cases to consider. I'll update the answer anyway...

Comment: Actually, I was still having some problems using the solution from Dimitrii.  Using your update code has resolved them and has worked as I had hope.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like `'/(?<![\'])\b'.$row['word'].'\b/i'`.

Comment: This seemed to work but then broke other parts. When I use this I get results like this,  He's My Brother She's My Sister  --> HE.'s My Brother ShE.'s My SisTer.  Because E. is for East and Ter. is for Terrace.  I trying to get exact matches but for some reason my first code did it as expected unless it was followed by an apostrophe.  Scratching my head on this.

Comment: Could you show your updated code? I wonder how it is possible

Comment: I'm sorry you are correct, I just ran it again and it worked as expected.  It must have been a user error.  Thank you so much for your help.  Both your example and fab's answer seem to work for my issue.

Comment: Again thanks for your help, but If I wanted a nice to have what if I didn't want it replace words that are proceeded by a symbol such as Drive-By Truckers right now it gets converted to Dr.-By Truckers because an abbreviation is set up for Drive and Dr.

Comment: You can add lookahead assertion to the end of the pattern for that purpose. Try `'/(?<![\'])\b'.$row['word'].'\b(?![\'-])/i'`, it will match `Drive`, but not `Drive's` or `Drive-By`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off tokenizing the input and checking for replacements in a callback rather than searching multiple times for each word to replace.

```php
function abbreviate($str, $abbr) {
    // Define a "word" as a utf-8 string beginning with a letter character
    // followed by as many letter characters or apostrophes as possible.
    // You will probably have to tweak this.
    $re = '/\w[\w\']*/u';
    $callback = function($matches) use ($abbr) {
        $replacement = $matches[0];
        $word = mb_strtolower($matches[0], 'utf-8');
        if (isset($abbr[$word])) {
            $replacement = $abbr[$word];
        }
        return $replacement;
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($re, $callback, $str);
}

echo abbreviate("Heaven's Basement\n", array('s'=>'S.'));
echo abbreviate("S College Rd\n", array('s' => 'South', 'rd'=> 'Road'));
```

Prints:

```
Heaven's Basement
South College Road
```